# How to check if Directory is Accessable without catching System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, directory, access-violation

I have searched and searched through the net but couldn't find a good solution for this problem.

Here my code:

```
protected bool isFileValid(FileSystemInfo ifo)
{
   if (!ifo.Exists || ifo.Name.StartsWith("$") || ifo.Name.Equals("System Volume Information"))
        return false;
   if(ifo is DirectoryInfo){
        try
        {
           ((DirectoryInfo)ifo).GetFileSystemInfos();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { LogUtil.Debug("Exception in isFileValid" + e.Message); return false; }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Is there any way to check if I can access the Directory other than to try catch the Exception? The problem with this approach is that it gets really slow if there are many directories I cannot access.

What I mean by "access the Directory" is the call of `GetFileSystemInfos()` without exception. `isFileValid` is called by my application for every `FileSystemInfo` to determine if it is accessible in the way I described.

Thanks in advance for any ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the `DirectoryInfo.Exists` Property ([documentation link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.exists.aspx))

> The Exists property returns false if any error occurs while trying to
>   determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations
>   that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid
>   characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or **if
>   the caller does not have permission to read the file.**

(Emphasis added is mine).

So here is a quick example:

```
var di = (DirectoryInfo)ifo;
if(di.Exists)
{
    di.GetFileSystemInfos();
}
```

**Edit:** It sounds like you've got environment variables at work. Somewhere before this method is called, I guess you create the `FileSystemInfo` from a file path, stored in a string. You need to expand it there like this:

```
string expandedFilePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(filePath);
```

before creating a `FileSystemInfo` from that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly it does not work :/
In the code i posted i already check if `ifo.Exists` is `false`. But even if it is `true`, you get an exception when trying to call `GetFileSystemInfos` on a Directory like "%USER%\Application Data"

(i also tried to cast the `FileSystemInfo` to a `DirectoryInfo` before calling `Exists`)

Comment: @user1531730 Sorry, didn't see that in your code! YOu don't mention where you're getting these from, but that looks like it's based off environment variables! I'll add a bit to my answer.

Comment: @user1531730 I've added a bit more that might help. It might be worth adding your example file path it fails on to the original question!

Comment: nope i do not work with environment variables. My FileSystemInfos are just as i already wrote, created by calling `GetFileSystemInfos` to the Parent Directory. Only the "Root" DirectoryInfo is created with the string constructor, but also this one does not contain environment variables.
There must be a way to check if the call of `GetFileSystemInfos` on a Directoy is valid other than simply try it and catch the exception. But it seems that this is not an easy one :(